# Why will the iPad not auto-lock and turn its screen off after the set time has expired?

Tags: macos, ipad, screen-lock, universal-control

- The iPad's auto-lock settings are set to 5 minutes.
- Running iOS 16.5.

For some reason the iPad does not auto-lock after 5 minutes of inactivity.

Reboots did not help.

(I thought it was a localized iPad issue, but I missed to oversee the combined system. I thought I would add it as a question here because there is a lot out there that overlaps with issues from the iPad's past.)

Answer (score 3):

#### Universal Control via your Mac might keep your iPad unlocked.

- When iPad is used with Universal Control, one can use the Mac's Mouse and Keyboard on the iPad.
- Even when the iPad is moved away from the Mac, having a different context, the range of Universal Control can be really large.
- When you are actually using it, it's very practical the iPad remains unlocked.
- At the moment of writing there is no visual indicator on the iPad the it is being controlled by a nearby Mac. (Except the mouse cursor when it enters the iPad's screen.)

### Simple fix:

In MacOS's Control Centre, under Display, click to disconnect the MacOS's keyboard and mouse from the iPad in question. If you ever need it again, you can turn it on there too, provided you iPad is unlocked.

[image: Example] ([Source of image](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2023/01/05/how-to-use-mac-keyboard-mouse-trackpad-with-ipad/))

### Next:

In MacOS settings, under Display settings \ Advanced there is a toggle that allows the Mac to automatically reconnect to devices connected to before. You might want to consider disabling if you only use it occasionally.

#### Reference:

https://www.idownloadblog.com/2023/01/05/how-to-use-mac-keyboard-mouse-trackpad-with-ipad/